# Update subscription payment via Paypal or Google Wallet

Tags: paypal, credit-card, subscription, google-checkout, android-pay

I currently allow subscriptions via Paypal and Google Wallet.  I'm looking for additional functionality that will allow me to modify the amount of (or add to)  subscription payment per user's usage.

For example: if user subscribed to $5 a month plan and decides to buy additional feature for $2, I need a way to add that $2 to current $5 subscription amount as an one-off payment.

There is already a solution like that with [Stripe Metered Payments](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions#metered-billing-and-one-time-charges) I'm curious if I can accomplish same with Paypal and GoogleWallet.

It looks like this could be done with:

[Paypal Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/how-to-guides/how-set-payment-preapproval-using-adaptive-payments) by pre-approving payments

[Merchant Handled subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Beta_Subscriptions#Merchant_Handled_Subscriptions) for Google Wallet.

Comment: Are you currently using Paypal's Express Checkout API? If not, which API are you using?

Comment: Currently using Paypal Pro. Using their subscription buttons.

Answer (score 3):

For Google Wallet, once the subscription is set up you cannot change the maximum-charge, so make sure to allow for price increases for the additional features the user may purchase.

For better transactions fees, you may also want to have a look at the newly launched Google Wallet subscriptions for digital goods:

https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/

https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/subscriptions